# UIView animation options have no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, ios9

I am trying to apply an easing animation to a UILabel translation, but if I do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
   CGRect frame = _section.frame;
   frame.origin.y = -100;
   _section.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

I see a linear animation, the same result as when I pass `0` as the `options`.

How can I get the animation options working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work, assuming you are NOT using AutoLayout.

If you are using AutoLayout then all bets are off. With AutoLayout you're supposed to use constraints to do your animation. You'd set up a constraint, connect it to an IBOutlet, and inside your animation block change the constraint's constant value and call layoutIfNeeded on the view you're animating.

Comment: I've seen an alternative method were you set the constraint to the new value _outside_ the animation block, and only call layoutIfNeeded() inside it. Not sure why both methods work.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter where you change the constraint (inside the animation block or outside.) What matters is that the call to layoutIfNeeded is inside the animation block. The call to layoutIfNeeded is what actually moves the view, and that's what you want to animate. The constraint change just sets the stage so that the next time the layout is updated the views (might) get moved around.

Comment: how do I check if autolayout is on? (I inherited this project) - I see "Autoresize Subviews" checked on the storyboard, is that it? (I just tried unchecking, but still see linear animations)

Comment: Select your storyboard. Open the "File Inspector". Look in the section labeled "Interface Builder Document". There will be a checkbox "Use Auto Layout." If it's checked, your storyboard is using Auto Layout.

Comment: BTW, don't change the state of that checkbox without understanding what that entails. It may require substantial rework of your app.

Comment: ok, its on. I guess I'll have to disable that and rework the project. I'd like to remove the storyboard altogether anyways, so this will help me along that path. really wish Apple wasn't pushing those things so much, It's super annoying to realize your code is being overriden by some checkbox buried in a visual editor...

Comment: I disabled auto layout and fixed everything, but the curve animations still do not work. What else could be the problem?

Comment: oh actually `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` just looks linear when you are fading something out. It works fine with other animation options